# react-router paths keep redirecting to 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a router link that works successfully taking me to a product-management page:

```
<Route
  path='/auth/products/product-management'
  render={() => <ProdManagement {...this.props} />}
/>
<Redirect path="*" to="/404" />
```

Inside the `ProdManagement` component I have two buttons that onClick should take me to other pages:

```js
const addProduct = () => {
  props.history.push('/auth/products/add-product')
}
const editProduct = () => {
  props.history.push('/auth/products/edit-product')
}
```

The return for `ProdManagement` component has the routes set looks like this:

```
return (
  <div> 
    <Switch>         
      <Route
        exact
        path='/auth/products/add-product'
        render={() => <AddProduct {...this.props} />}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path='/auth/products/edit-product'
        render={() => <EditProduct {...this.props} />}
      />
    </Switch>
  </div>
)
```

But every time I click the buttons I get sent to the 404 page.
Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?
I know the `addProduct()` function is being called as I log something to the console.

UPDATE:
I moved the two routes (add & edit) to the same level as the main `/auth/products/product-management` and they work now.
Not sure why, but it fixed them.

Comment: You have route switch & button both in return of ProdManagement component?

Comment: yes I do.  I guessed this was the issue when I moved the routes up a level.

Comment: why not define all the routes at same place where your defined product-management route

Comment: I am restricting access to the product management area. So I was managing all the product management routes within that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProdManagement` component is rendered on path `"/auth/products/product-management"` and when it triggers navigation actions to paths `"/auth/products/add-product"` or `"/auth/products/edit-product"` the path now no longer matches `"/auth/products/product-management"` and `ProdManagement` is unmounted so the other paths are not mounted and `<Redirect path="*" to="/404"/>` is what is left to render.

As it seems you've discovered, the easy solution is to just declare the routes where they are always mounted and matchable.

```
<Switch>
  ... other more specific routes ...

  <Route
    path="/auth/products/product-management"
    component={ProdManagement}
  />
  <Route exact path="/auth/products/add-product" component={AddProduct} /> 
  <Route exact path="/auth/products/edit-product" component={EditProduct} />

  ... other less specific routes ...
 
  <Redirect path="*" to="/404" />
</Switch>
```